# convert base64 string into byte array and save in mp3 file format in java

Tags: java, xml, file, audio, base64

I am having a problem with writing an MP3 file on Linux.  Here is my situation:

I have an XML message that is coming over JMS.  The XML has an element that is a Base64 encoded string which represents an MP3 audio file.  In marshalling the XML to Objects, I use JIBX. JIBX will then convert the Base64 encoded String to byte[].  I, then, write the byte[] to the file system using FileUtils from the commons-io project.

```
void writeMP3File(final byte[] data, final String filePath) throws IOException {

    final File mp3File = new File(basePath + IOUtils.DIR_SEPARATOR + filePath);

    mp3File.getParentFile().mkdirs(); // Ensure any parent directories are created

    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(mp3File, data);
}
```

When I try to play the file later, the MP3 player will not play the file.  Also, when I go to the file system and look at the file, I get:

> > file TestFile1.mp3
>   TestFile1.mp3: ASCII text, with no line terminators

I tried using FileOutputStream to write the file, as well; and the same result happens.  How do you write a byte[] to a file and set the file type of MPEG.  So, what I want to see on the file system is:

> > file TestFile1.mp3
>   TestFile1.mp3: MPEG ADTS, layer III,  v2.5,   8 kBits, 8 kHz, Monaural

Comment: I have never used any of these technologies, but. I would say take a known MP3 file, pull up its contents as plaintext. Then send a copy of it through your system above, and compare the output of it to the original. See if there are any differences that can be attributed to one of those technologies.

Comment: I would if I could get a copy of the original file.

Comment: Then, try to compare the output file with the MP3 file format? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3

Comment: Finally figured out the problem.  The original sender took the MP3 Base64 encoded it with Apache commons-codec Base64.  Then had their JIBX settings set to Base64 encode the already Base64 encoded data.  Double Base64 enconding. Just an FYI, to anyone else who comes across this problem:
1. When using JIBX and setting the type="byte[]", JIBX will automatically convert the data to Base64.
2. With FileOutputStream, It is up to you to ensure the data is in the correct file format.
4. There is a 'base64' command that is part of the GNU Core utils that will help validate your encoding is correct.